# How to switch back to original button image after delay (obj-c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Hi I am trying to make a simple app that includes buttons changing images on click. I would like them to switch back to the original after a delay of 2 - 3 seconds. Im new to objective c and cant figure out how to do it. I've tried variations of the code below. Since there are several buttons I'd need to retain the sender id or image name. Thanks in advance!

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {   
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"new.jpg"];
    [sender setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];

    UIImage *origImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orig.jpg"];
    [sender setImage:origImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add two target of your Button with **StateHighlighted** and **StateNormal**, such like,,,

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-active.png", i]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMenuPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoList:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not to change button image. Follow this:

Your `UIButton` will have to images for two states, `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateSelected` in `loadView` or in `viewDidLoad` of in `xib` itself.

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"original.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"new.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

when a user will click on button, button will turn to `[UIImage imageNamed:@"new.jpg"]` itself. Then inside `playSound` method fire a `NSTimer`

```
-(IBAction)playSound:(id)sender
{
    [self aTimer];
}

- (void)aTimer
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:self.view repeats:NO];
}

- (void)changeImage
{
    [button setSelected:NO];
}
```

Comment: It is saying button is undefined in changeImage? Maybe because I did the state changes in the xib..

Comment: `button` is that  `UIButton`'s object you want to change image.